# input validation after if statement

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

When trying a regular expression for no characters my winforms EnterValue is still being triggered after the if statement, how can I stop it from going any further after the trigger?

```
    private void EnterValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please only enter numbers");
            textBox1.Clear();
        }

        //convert input to double
        listDouble.Add(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text)); // this line still throws exception
        textBox1.Clear();
        //clear existing items
        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        // clear any existing list items
        for (int i = 0; i < listDouble.Count; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(listDouble[i]);
        }
        //for each value added, add this to our list 
    }
```

Comment: You should *only* use the `Validating` event for input validation, nothing else. This is the only correct time point to perform validation at. `Click` is wrong. Also, your equality test with `string.Empty` is redundant, and even if it weren’t, don’t use `string.Empty`, use `""` – it’s shorter and *at least* as readable. You don’t use `int.Zero`, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return from the method:

```
if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please only enter numbers");
    textBox1.Clear();
    return; // nothing after this will execute
}
```

This will execute only if the `if` predicate is true, and the method will return as soon as the `return;` statement has been hit, without any of the other code being run.

Answer (score 1):

First option is to use `return`:

```
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please only enter numbers");
        textBox1.Clear();
        return; // exit method
    }
```

Second option is to use `else`:

```
    if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty && !Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"^[0-9]+$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please only enter numbers");
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        // your statements
    }
```

Comment: I like the first method better, as it reduces the indentation level for the rest of the code.

Comment: I agree, personally I'd use `return`. I wanted to show that this can also be done using `if { } else { }` statements.

Comment: I used to prefer the `return`-method, but not anymore. If you return, then it becomes harder to see that the rest of the function only executes sometimes. The `return` statement works almost like a `goto` statement and obscures the code flow.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DECIMAL.TRYPARSE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true). And use [`return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28RETURN_CSHARPKEYWORD%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) after checking condition to exit from current method:

> The **`return`** statement terminates execution of the method in which it appears and returns control to the calling method.

```
Decimal dec;
if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dec))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please only enter numbers");
    textBox1.Clear();
    return;
}
```

Comment: @JungleBoogie: I changed `int` to `Decimal`.